# View docker entrypoint output

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I'm configuring an entrypoint to be executed after the container is started:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT exec /entrypoint.sh
```

However, I'm not able to see the output of `entrypoint.sh` execution when `docker-compose up`.

The only output is:

> service exited with code 2

The container is killed so I cannot do `docker logs <container_id>`

I've tried with `docker events` command but I don't see any logs related to `entrypoint.sh`.

I know the entrypoint file has an error, but I'd like to see the output of the execution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible it's printing nothing and exiting immediately?  The output of the entrypoint _is_ the output of the container and it shouldn't get suppressed.  If it's there, don't include a `docker-compose up -d` option so the container starts in the foreground and you see its output, but I'm guessing you're already doing this.

Comment: If your shell is GNU bash, ["All builtins return an exit status of 2 to indicate incorrect usage"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#Exit-Status).  Just specifying `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]` avoids invoking a shell entirely.

Comment: The other debugging step worth trying is to change this `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` (permanently), `docker-compose run yourcontainer bash`, and run `/entrypoint.sh` by hand at an interactive shell prompt.  You won't be process ID 1 but you'll otherwise be inside the container environment, and you can try things like `sh -x /entrypoint.sh` to trace the script execution.

Comment: run the same container manually, override the entrypoint to give you a shell, then execute the script manually to see what happens when you run it. If you don't find the error that way, report back with the results.